# Any performance benefits for MongoDB UUID Standard instead of Legacy?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Are there any performance benefits to switching to the new standard [UUID BinData subtype 4](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DOCS-1543)?
Most of our collections are set to use the `GuidRepresenation.CSharpLegacy` which is is [the default](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/src/MongoDB.Bson/BsonDefaults.cs#L31) for the C# driver. If I set `Mongo.Bson.BsonDefaults.GuidPresenation = Mongo.Bson.GuidRepresentation.Standard`, will it benefit performance? Also assume we convert all existing data to use the standard subtype.

Answer (score 6):

#### Short version

The different UUID BinData subtypes are about *compatibility*, not performance .. so there are no obvious performance benefits.

#### Long version

Historically (and by that I mean, several years ago) [ObjectIDs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/) were just expected to be unique and generated with a similar formula. Some of the drivers diverged in how they serialised their UUIDs (for example, differing in byte order or endianness) .. so [type 3 UUIDs](http://bsonspec.org/spec.html) ended up having Python, Java, and C# subtypes.

This variation isn't an issue if you are only using a single driver, but can potentially be a problem if you use different drivers on the same database (for example C# vs Java vs Python). Differences in how the ObjectIDs are generated may affect the driver's assumptions on the ordering or interpretation of sub-values (for example, if you want to extract the `timestamp` component of an ObjectID).

If you want some insight into how the formats differ, have a look at [uuidhelpers.js](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/uuidhelpers.js) in the mongo-csharp-driver repository. This script includes some helper functions for working with different UUID formats in the `mongo` shell.